# How to show formatted text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some values that I have written in php. The var `here` is derived from `nl2br $ther`. The code is written so that it removes certain words from the `here` array, but I do not want to remove some values such as

```
  "<br/>"
```

and `\n` to preserve the formatting.
I tried the following code (and a combination of others but it is not working)

```
<script = "javascript">
var r = <?php echo json_encode($t, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>; // getting random nu.
 var here = <?php echo json_encode($ther, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
 var jtotal = <?php echo json_encode($total, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;

var count =0;
for(var b=0; b < jtotal; b++)  {

if ((b==r) && (here[b] = "<br")) {
   document.write("<br");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] = "/>")) {
 document.write("/>");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] = "\n")) {
 document.write("\n");
}

 else if (b==r){
count = count+1;
document.write("____(" + count+ ")____");
r=r+2; 
}

else {

    document.write(here[b] + " ");
}

</script>
```

Comment: If you are getting this from PHP (on parsing time), why using JS instead of using PHP to get back what you formatted?

Comment: There is a little story about that - I got a book on javascript that influenced me so I ended up writing all the program in javascript with only very very few PHP. I have already written the rest of the program in javascript so I need to fix this in javascript.

Comment: If everything prints out (you never said what was the error, only the expected behavior), check MrT's answer. You are doing comparison with assignment operator..

Comment: Why not use frameworks like for example nextjs, javascripts PHP "equivalent"? Then you could go javascript all the way :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var b=0; b < jtotal; b++)  {

if ((b==r) && (here[b] = "<br")) {
   document.write("<br");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] = "/>")) {
 document.write("/>");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] = "\n")) {
 document.write("\n");
}
```

to this

```
for(var b=0; b < jtotal; b++)  {

if ((b==r) && (here[b] == "<br")) {
   document.write("<br");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] == "/>")) {
 document.write("/>");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] == "\n")) {
 document.write("\n");
}
```

**the issue:** you're not using a comparison operator, rather an assignment operator.

Comment: I did upvote but I do not have enough reputation, to make any impact on upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script = "javascript">
var r = <?php echo json_encode($t, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>; // getting random nu.
 var here = <?php echo json_encode($ther, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
 var jtotal = <?php echo json_encode($total, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;

var count =0;
for(var b=0; b < jtotal; b++)  {

if ((b==r) && (here[b] == "<br")) {
   document.write("<br");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] == "/>")) {
 document.write("/>");
}
else if ((b==r) && (here[b] == "\n")) {
 document.write("\n");
}

 else if (b==r){
count = count+1;
document.write("____(" + count+ ")____");
r=r+2; 
}

else {

    document.write(here[b] + " ");
}
```

I think your Comparison Operators is missing "=".
Hope helpful.

Comment: That solved my problem partially. Now the code sometimes works and sometimes does not. The code is not "document.write("____(" + count+ ")____");" at regular intervals based on r = r+2 ;

Comment: your mean you get error or nothing print out. Can you show list prints out?

Comment: variables here , jtotal are not changed with each run. and r is radom value. right?and What is the rule in php code?

Comment: So my use of r (random value) is incorrect? I am getting t in php this way $t = rand(1,5);

Comment: What is the value of each element in the array "here"?

Comment: I know the probable defect - the code breaks down at places where there is a space.Since I cannot access the code right now, I will let you know about it after 8 hours. I also do not know how to see the formatting HTML codes from an array output. The formatting will show the result, but I cannot see which HTML values it is taking - by using for loop and document.write command.

Comment: By using <pre> tag, I got rid of the <br /> and other formatting. But now I have an array with some (\r\n) as values. How do I make sure this value is preserved ( while replacing it with blanks) and shows the line breaks on its exact position.